# Gstreamer AAC encoding no more supported?

Tags: ubuntu, ffmpeg, gstreamer, aac

i'd like to include AAC as one of the compatible formats in my app but i'm having troubles with its encoding.
FAAC seems to be missing in GStreamer-1.0 Debian-derived packages (see Ubuntu) and the main reason for that (if i got it correctly) is the presence of avenc_aac ([Lunchpad bugreport](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gst-plugins-bad1.0/+bug/1299376)) as a replacement.

I've tried the following:

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location="src.avi" ! tee name=t  t.! queue ! decodebin ! progressreport ! x264enc ! mux. t.! queue ! decodebin ! audioconvert ! audioresample ! avenc_aac compliance=-2 ! mux. avmux_mpegts name=mux ! filesink location=/tmp/test.avi
```

It hangs prerolling with:

```
ERROR libav :0:: AAC bitstream not in ADTS format and extradata missing
```

Using mpegtsmux instead of avmux_mpegts seems to work since the file is created but it results with no working audio (with some players it's completely unplayable).

This is the trace of mplayer:

```
Opening audio decoder: [ffmpeg] FFmpeg/libavcodec audio decoders
[aac @ 0x7f2860d6c3c0]channel element 3.15 is not allocated
[aac @ 0x7f2860d6c3c0]Sample rate index in program config element does not match the sample rate index configured by the container.
[aac @ 0x7f2860d6c3c0]Inconsistent channel configuration.
[aac @ 0x7f2860d6c3c0]get_buffer() failed
[aac @ 0x7f2860d6c3c0]Assuming an incorrectly encoded 7.1 channel layout instead of a spec-compliant 7.1(wide) layout, use -strict 1 to decode according to the specification instead.
[aac @ 0x7f2860d6c3c0]Reserved bit set.
[aac @ 0x7f2860d6c3c0]Number of bands (20) exceeds limit (14).
[aac @ 0x7f2860d6c3c0]invalid band type
[aac @ 0x7f2860d6c3c0]More than one AAC RDB per ADTS frame is not implemented. Update your FFmpeg version to the newest one from Git. If the problem still occurs, it means that your file has a feature which has not been implemented.
[aac @ 0x7f2860d6c3c0]Reserved bit set.
[aac @ 0x7f2860d6c3c0]Number of bands (45) exceeds limit (28).
Unknown/missing audio format -> no sound
ADecoder init failed :(
Opening audio decoder: [faad] AAC (MPEG2/4 Advanced Audio Coding)
FAAD: compressed input bitrate missing, assuming 128kbit/s!
AUDIO: 44100 Hz, 2 ch, floatle, 128.0 kbit/9.07% (ratio: 16000->176400)
Selected audio codec: [faad] afm: faad (FAAD AAC (MPEG-2/MPEG-4 Audio))
==========================================================================
AO: [pulse] 44100Hz 2ch floatle (4 bytes per sample)
Starting playback...
FAAD: error: Bitstream value not allowed by specification, trying to resync!
FAAD: error: Invalid number of channels, trying to resync!
FAAD: error: Invalid number of channels, trying to resync!
FAAD: error: Bitstream value not allowed by specification, trying to resync!
FAAD: error: Invalid number of channels, trying to resync!
FAAD: error: Bitstream value not allowed by specification, trying to resync!
FAAD: error: Channel coupling not yet implemented, trying to resync!
FAAD: error: Invalid number of channels, trying to resync!
FAAD: error: Invalid number of channels, trying to resync!
FAAD: error: Bitstream value not allowed by specification, trying to resync!
FAAD: Failed to decode frame: Bitstream value not allowed by specification 
Movie-Aspect is 1.33:1 - prescaling to correct movie aspect.
VO: [vdpau] 640x480 => 640x480 Planar YV12 
A:3602.2 V:3600.0 A-V:  2.143 ct:  0.000   3/  3 ??% ??% ??,?% 0 0 
FAAD: error: Array index out of range, trying to resync!
FAAD: error: Bitstream value not allowed by specification, trying to resync!
FAAD: error: Bitstream value not allowed by specification, trying to resync!
FAAD: error: Unexpected fill element with SBR data, trying to resync!
FAAD: error: Bitstream value not allowed by specification, trying to resync!
FAAD: error: Bitstream value not allowed by specification, trying to resync!
FAAD: error: Channel coupling not yet implemented, trying to resync!
FAAD: error: Invalid number of channels, trying to resync!
FAAD: error: PCE shall be the first element in a frame, trying to resync!
FAAD: error: Invalid number of channels, trying to resync!
FAAD: Failed to decode frame: Invalid number of channels 
A:3602.2 V:3600.1 A-V:  2.063 ct:  0.000   4/  4 ??% ??% ??,?% 0 0
```

These the messages produced by VLC (10 seconds of playback):

```
ts info: MPEG-4 descriptor not found for pid 0x42 type 0xf
core error: option sub-original-fps does not exist
subtitle warning: failed to recognize subtitle type
core error: no suitable demux module for `file/subtitle:///tmp//test.avi.idx'
avcodec info: Using NVIDIA VDPAU Driver Shared Library 361.42 Tue Mar 22 17:29:16 PDT 2016 for hardware decoding.
core warning: VoutDisplayEvent 'pictures invalid'
core warning: VoutDisplayEvent 'pictures invalid'
packetizer_mpeg4audio warning: Invalid ADTS header
packetizer_mpeg4audio warning: ADTS CRC not supported
packetizer_mpeg4audio warning: Invalid ADTS header
packetizer_mpeg4audio error: Multiple blocks per frame in ADTS not supported
packetizer_mpeg4audio warning: Invalid ADTS header
packetizer_mpeg4audio error: Multiple blocks per frame in ADTS not supported
packetizer_mpeg4audio warning: ADTS CRC not supported
packetizer_mpeg4audio error: Multiple blocks per frame in ADTS not supported
packetizer_mpeg4audio error: Multiple blocks per frame in ADTS not supported
packetizer_mpeg4audio error: Multiple blocks per frame in ADTS not supported
packetizer_mpeg4audio error: Multiple blocks per frame in ADTS not supported
packetizer_mpeg4audio error: Multiple blocks per frame in ADTS not supported
packetizer_mpeg4audio error: Multiple blocks per frame in ADTS not supported
packetizer_mpeg4audio error: Multiple blocks per frame in ADTS not supported
packetizer_mpeg4audio error: Multiple blocks per frame in ADTS not supported
packetizer_mpeg4audio warning: Invalid ADTS header
packetizer_mpeg4audio error: Multiple blocks per frame in ADTS not supported
packetizer_mpeg4audio warning: Invalid ADTS header
packetizer_mpeg4audio warning: Invalid ADTS header
packetizer_mpeg4audio error: Multiple blocks per frame in ADTS not supported
packetizer_mpeg4audio warning: Invalid ADTS header
packetizer_mpeg4audio warning: Invalid ADTS header
packetizer_mpeg4audio warning: Invalid ADTS header
packetizer_mpeg4audio error: Multiple blocks per frame in ADTS not supported
packetizer_mpeg4audio warning: Invalid ADTS header
packetizer_mpeg4audio warning: Invalid ADTS header
packetizer_mpeg4audio error: Multiple blocks per frame in ADTS not supported
packetizer_mpeg4audio warning: Invalid ADTS header
packetizer_mpeg4audio error: Multiple blocks per frame in ADTS not supported
packetizer_mpeg4audio error: Multiple blocks per frame in ADTS not supported
packetizer_mpeg4audio error: Multiple blocks per frame in ADTS not supported
packetizer_mpeg4audio error: Multiple blocks per frame in ADTS not supported
packetizer_mpeg4audio error: Multiple blocks per frame in ADTS not supported
packetizer_mpeg4audio error: Multiple blocks per frame in ADTS not supported
packetizer_mpeg4audio warning: Invalid ADTS header
packetizer_mpeg4audio error: Multiple blocks per frame in ADTS not supported
packetizer_mpeg4audio error: Multiple blocks per frame in ADTS not supported
packetizer_mpeg4audio error: Multiple blocks per frame in ADTS not supported
packetizer_mpeg4audio error: Multiple blocks per frame in ADTS not supported
packetizer_mpeg4audio error: Multiple blocks per frame in ADTS not supported
packetizer_mpeg4audio error: Multiple blocks per frame in ADTS not supported
packetizer_mpeg4audio error: Multiple blocks per frame in ADTS not supported
```

Using the error of the hanging pipeline I've finally discovered that avenc_aac should be told in such way to output the data NOT in RAW AAC but in ADTS AAC, the point is that i've no idea how to do that with Gstreamer. See here, bottom of the page: [FFMPEG Ticket](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/1872)

At this point since i've found no documentation seems right to say we have no support for AAC encoding in GStreamer... which isn't true, i guess! (IMHO anyway seems strange the missing of FAAC if AVENC_AAC requires all the time to be set in experimental mode)

Can someone propose a working pipeline for this?

**UPDATE**

After some more research i've found (via gst-inspect on avenc_aac) what i'm probably looking for but i don't know how to setup it as needed.
Have a look at stream-format:

```
Pad Templates:
  SRC template: 'src'
    Availability: Always
    Capabilities:
      audio/mpeg
               channels: [ 1, 6 ]
                   rate: [ 4000, 96000 ]
            mpegversion: 4
          stream-format: raw
        base-profile: lc
```

Thanks

Comment: Hi, were you able to solve your problem?

I have tried with   below, but no output gets generated: ---------------------------
gst-launch-1.0 --gst-debug-level=3  dvbsrc modulation="QAM 256" trans-mode=8k bandwidth=8 frequency=147000000 ! tee name=t  t.! queue ! decodebin ! progressreport ! x264enc ! mux. t.! queue ! decodebin ! audioconvert ! audioresample ! avenc_aac compliance=-2 ! mux. avmux_mpegts name=mux ! filesink  location=test_streamer.avi

Answer (score 0):

There is also `voaacenc` which is an AAC encoder. Also try adding `aacparse` after the AAC encoder element.